# I am trying to extract an XMLTYPE column from an Oracle table using JDBC and having some issues

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, xmltype

I am trying to extract an XMLTYPE column from an Oracle table using JDBC.
I have the query:

```
    select "XML_FILE" FROM "TABLE_NAME"
```

and when I run the query in the Oracle SQL Developer, it returns back all the XMLTYPE rows completely fine.

But, when I run the following Java code, and run the same query, I always get "null" returned for every column.  I'm not sure what could be going wrong and I've tried doing many different things, but nothing has been working.  Important note - the XMLTYPE fields each have an XML file with at most 60,000 lines of XML.

The Java code I'm using:

```
String query = "select \"XML_FILE\" FROM \"TABLE_NAME\"";
//creating PreparedStatement object to execute query
PreparedStatement preStatement = null;
try {
   System.out.println("QUERY: "+query);
   preStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);   //con is the Connection obj
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();  
}

ResultSet result = null;
try {
   result = preStatement.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();  
}
System.out.println("RESULT SET: "+result.toString());
String dataResult = "";
while(result.next()){
   for(int i=1; i<=numCols; i++){
      dataResult += result.getObject(i)+"\t";
      //dataResult += result.getString(i)+"\t";
   }
   dataResult+="\n";
   System.out.println("RESULT: \'"+dataResult+"\'");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve this as string (varchar), because of limitations of varchar lenght (4000bytes).
Select it as CLOB:

```
    String query = "SELECT TBL.XMLTYPECOLUMN.GETCLOBVAL() FROM TABLE TBL";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    xmlClob = (Clob) rs.getClob(1);
```

http://kodehelp.com/how-to-read-xmltype-column-from-database-using-jdbc/

Comment: This seems like it would work, but when I run the query in Oracle, it gives me the error "ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis". Any idea why it would be throwing that error?

Comment: you can get rid of ORA-00906 by using additional brackets. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465260/the-mystic-getclobval

Answer (score 1):

Have to use `to_clob` in the query
select

```
to_clob(xmlelement ( "employee", 'Bob' ))  ) as SQLXMLCOL1 from dual
```

then use the `toString()` in `resultSet`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your call to result.toString() is returning null?  If so, that's not how you get the data from the result set anyway.  I tried a couple of different test, using the DataDirect Oracle JDBC driver and only got null from result.toString().  If I call rs.getString() for the XMLType column, I would get the XML data I inserted;  Calling getObject() returned to LOB locator (I think, didn't double check) that references the data.  Printing that did not give me the data, just the ID for the locator.