# The mystic getClobVal()

Tags: oracle, comments, clob, xmltype

I have a table (AKADMIN) with an XMLTYPE column which name is XML.
I would like to use the getClobVal() with this column.

```
select t.xml.getClobVal() /**/ 
,      t.xml.getClobVal() --
,      t.xml.getClobVal() as clobval
,      t.xml.getClobVal()
from akadmin t where ROWID = 'AAAQc6AAIAAAADDAAA' ;
```

In the resultset the first 4 column give CLOB type, but the fifth column XMLTYPE. I have to type any comment or alias after getClobVal() to correct (CLOB) type of the result. Why?

Another issue, when I leave the alias of tablename:

```
select xml.getClobVal()
from akadmin t where ROWID = 'AAAQc6AAIAAAADDAAA' ;
```

It throws an `ORA-00904 string: invalid identifier`
Hmmm...

Does anybody have any idea?

Addition info about environment:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0; 
PL/SQL Developer 10.0.5.1710

But a tried this in our Java apllication via OJDBC6 with same results

Comment: The second part is because the period [makes this look like two pieces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/general008.htm), and the first piece (`xml`) can't be resolved. Including the table name/alias makes *that* the first piece. For the rest, how are you determining the data types you're getting back? Where are you executing this and where do you see the types? If you create a view from that (for example) and describe that view, all four columns are `CLOB`. So really not sure what you're doing...

Comment: I tried this:
`Select xmlsomething.getClobVal() From (Select xml As xmlsomething From AKADMIN_v v Where Rowid = 'AAAQc6AAIAAAADDAAA');`

Comment: I tried the original select in SQL Window of PL/SQL Developer. The type of result columns shown in PL/SQL Developer [result grid](http://pichost.me/1916289/)

Comment: They all show as `<CLOB>` in PL/SQL Developer 8.0.1, against an 11gR2 database. So don't know if you're maybe seeing a PL/SQL Developer bug, or an Oracle bug - possibly version-dependent whichever it is...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put xml in a brackets:

```
select (xml).getClobVal() from akadmin;
```

works for me